# Getting integer values from TextCtrl-box in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I am writing a wx application where values entered into TextCtrl-boxes are to be used as arguments to functions. This does not work, and I am starting to suspect it's because they are not properly read from the beginning. I have a window with some of these boxes, and use the GetValue() function to get values from them, like this:

```
var = tc1.GetValue()
```

This causes an error further down the line where the values are not considered to be integers, as they are supposed to be. I tried to correct this, using this line:

```
var = int(tc1.GetValue())
```

This gives the error message "Value error: invalid literal for int() with base 10:". I have no idea what this means.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will get this error if you are trying to convert a non integer or a floating point number string to an integer. Your best bet is to put a `try: - except:` block to handle this error.

Try something like this:

```
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id,
                          'Read Number',
                          size = (200,150),
                          style=wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.RESIZE_BORDER 
    | wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION |  wx.CLOSE_BOX)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        widgetPanel=wx.Panel(self, -1)

        Button = wx.Button(widgetPanel, -1, "Read", pos=(10,10), size=(30,30))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.read, Button)
        Button.SetDefault()

        self.Text = wx.TextCtrl(widgetPanel, -1, "", pos=(10, 50), 
                                size =(100,30), style=wx.TE_CENTER)

        self.Text.SetFont(wx.Font(20, wx.DECORATIVE, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL))

    def read(self, event):
        try:
            var = int(float(self.Text.GetValue()))
            wx.MessageDialog(self, "You entered %s"%var, "Number entered", wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION).ShowModal()
        except:
            wx.MessageDialog(self, "Enter a number", "Warning!", wx.OK | wx.ICON_WARNING).ShowModal()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = Frame(parent=None,id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: How does the button know where it is supposed to read from? Can this solution be made to work with two TextCtrl:s, as I'm trying to do?

Comment: What is the idea with converting to float before converting to int as you and heinst recommend?

Comment: @user2536262 That is for incase someone enters a decimal number. You can remove it if you want! It's not necessary

Comment: @user2536262 The button simply calls the function self.read() when it is pressed. The function reads the value. If you want to read from 2 TextCtrls simply add that code to the read function. If you need any other help, try putting some of your code.

Comment: I worked with it some more, and understood how it worked. I also rewrote your script to take two values. For some reason it would not work with my original script. I've started a new thread, with code :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547435/wx-widget-wont-work-python

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a wx.lib.intctrl.IntCtrl

It provides a control that takes and returns integers as
value, and provides bounds support and optional value limiting.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var = float(tc1.GetValue())
```

I dont know what the exact value is, if the number you are trying to cast is a decimal or not, but if it is this should work.

Also, if the string value you are trying to covert (tc1.GetValue()) is empty, you will get this error as well.